# PHP replace image src and add a new attribute in image tag from a string containing different html tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a site where i get products description from database and decode html like this in PHP and display it on webpage frontend:

```
$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

It returns html like the following:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="textleft">
  <p>
   <span style="font-size:medium">
    <strong>Product Name:</strong>
   </span>
   <br />
   <span style="font-size:14px">Some description here <a href="some-link">Click here to see full details.</a></span>
   </p>
 </div>
 <div class="imageblock">
  <a href="some-link">
   <img src="http://myproject.com/image/catalog/image1.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;" />
  </a>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both">
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="textleft">
  <p>
   <span style="font-size:medium">
    <strong>Product Name:</strong>
   </span>
   <br />
   <span style="font-size:14px">Some description here <a href="some-link">Click here to see full details.</a></span>
   </p>
 </div>
 <div class="imageblock">
  <a href="some-link">
   <img src="http://myproject.com/image/catalog/image2.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;" />
  </a>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both">
</div>
```

There could be many images in the product description. I have added just 2 in my example. What I need to do is replace src of every image with `src="image/catalog/blank.gif"` for all images and add a new attribute

```
data-src="http://myproject.com/image/catalog/image1.jpg"
```

for image 1 and

`data-src="http://myproject.com/image/catalog/image2.jpg"`

for image 2. data-src attribute should get the original src value of each image. How can I achieve that?
I have tried preg_replace like following

```
$data['description'] = preg_replace('((\n)?src="\b.*?")', 'src="image/catalog/blank.gif', $data['description']);
```

It replaces src attribute of every image, but how can i add data-src with original image path. I need this before page load, so is there any way to do it with PHP?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply adjust your regular expression. Capture the text you want using (parentheses), then reference to that group 1 using $1 or \1.

```
preg_replace('(src="(.*?)")', 'src="image/catalog/blank.gif" data-src="$1"', $data['description']);
```

Demo: [Dead Link] https://repl.it/repls/SpottedZanyDiscussion

Comment: I want some more things if you can help:
1. Check if data-src does not already exist.
2. add a "lazy" class to the image tag if not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

```
$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data['description']);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    $new_src_url = 'image/catalog/blank.gif';
    $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
    $tag->setAttribute('data-src', $old_src);
}
$data['description'] = $doc->saveHTML();
```

I havn't tested this though, so don't just copy and paste.

Comment: i was trying this from few minutes, $data['description'] = $doc->saveHTML(); this is what i was missing. Thanks it worked out!